# program in binary to decimal in python using array list

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I'm new to programming and have a project to create a program to convert binary to decimal in Python. I have to make use of the values stored in the list and multiply based on user input. I keep getting errors regarding int/str.
 Any help would be appreciated.Please see code below of what I have so far.

```
denaryNumber = 0
binaryNumber = input("Please enter binary number: ")
placeValues = [128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
for i in range(0, len(binaryNumber) -1):
    denaryNumber = denaryNumber + (binaryNumber(i) * placeValues[i])
print (denaryNumber)
```

Comment: Can you quote an example here?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in your code.

- Every input by default in python is taken in as `'str'` , so your `binaryNumber` is str
- To access an element from a list, you use`[]` not `()` as you have used here: `binaryNumber(i)`
- Since your binary number is `str` you cant apply mathematical operations on `str` , so `binaryNumber(i) * placeValues[i]` is invalid. You need to type-cast str to int like this : `int(binaryNumber[i])`

So change your 2nd last line to this:

```
denaryNumber = denaryNumber + (int(binaryNumber[i]) * placeValues[i])
```

It would work then.

jbtw, your code would return correct results only if your input is 8bits.